# How to model a tenant per collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

I read up on the different approaches implementing multi-tentancy in MongoDB.  I settled on the tenant per collection approach.  Now what I want to know how it should look?  I already looked around.  I don't see any information on how actually model could look.

Can I have a single collection called "Tenant" that would have a tenantId, tenantName, etc.  and then have several other collections that have a link to the "Tenant" by tenantId?  Or should I ignore the "Tenant" collection all together and simple have a several different collections with tenantIds in them?

Comment: pretend you only have one tenant and you don't have to worry about multiple tenants. you have a collection for their data called X. That's it.  Now you have identical collections for each of the tenants with the collection *name* indicating whose collection it is.

Answer (score 0):

Read this http://support.mongohq.com/use-cases/multi-tenant.html it might be helpful to want your trying to accomplish